# How to prevent PHP DateTime modify when echo format?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

**Hello,**

I have a simple problem with outputing my DateTime object.

```
<?php

$today = new DateTime();
echo $today->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-07
echo $today->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-08
echo $today->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-08 but I want 2017-04-07
```

I really don't want to change my object at output. When I echo $x+1, $x is not changing it's value. How can I easily work with that? I need good technique to output my DataTime to DB in my CRON. I output it many times and declaring DateTime object before each output will ruin my code and effectivity (for example 50.000 users * 30 additional DateTime object declarations.)

**Please for help,**

Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you ?

```
$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2013-01-29');
$datetime = $start->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead simple `DateTime` use [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)

Each call to `DateTimeImmutable` object will return **new object**, so your source `$today` will not change.

```
$today = new DateTimeImmutable();
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL; // 2017-04-07
echo $today->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL; // 2017-04-08
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL; // 2017-04-07
```

Comment: I gave you +1 and the rule is a rule I need to give "best" to guy 1 minute before you :) Thanks.

Comment: Here's one minute after me, but it's okay)

Comment: Norbert Boros: 2017-04-07 16:37:10Z, u_mulder: 2017-04-07 16:37:25Z :)

Comment: You can’t stop me @_@ LOL

Answer (score 0):

Retain in variables

```
   $today = new DateTime();
    $first  = $today->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-07
    $second = $today->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-04-08
    echo $first;
    echo $second;
```